# Why doesn't DirectionalLight in three.js work?

Tags: javascript, three.js, light

I was doing a ring in **three.js**. I've needed to add camera and lighting. Camera work is ok, but I've got the problem with lighting. Here is my code:

```
<script src="three.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/../3rdparty/dat.gui.module.js"></script>
<script>

        const scene = new THREE.Scene();

        const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
        const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

        const color = 0xFFFFFF;
        const intensity = 1;
        const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(color, intensity);
        light.position.set(10, 10, 10);
        light.target.position.set(-5, 0, 0);
        scene.add(light);
        scene.add(light.target);

        document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

        let controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
        controls.target.set(0, 0, 0);
        controls.rotateSpeed = 0.5;
        controls.update();

        camera.position.z = 5;

        const geometry = new THREE.RingGeometry( 1, 3, 32 );
        const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffff00, side: THREE.DoubleSide } );
        const mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
        mesh.receiveShadow = true;
        mesh.castShadow = true
        scene.add( mesh );

        function animate() {
            requestAnimationFrame( animate );
            mesh.rotation.x += 0.01;
            mesh.rotation.y += 0.01;
            renderer.render( scene, camera );
        }
        animate();

</script>
```

I've tried to change `DirectionalLight` to `AmbientLight` and `SpotLight`, but they all didn't work either. It doesn't matter for me what kind of the light it would be, I've just need to show my 3d shape.

Comment: Is the issue solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`MeshBasicMaterial`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/MeshBasicMaterial) is not affected by lights. You have to use a different material. Use a [`MeshPhongMaterial`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/MeshPhongMaterial), that the [Blinn-Phong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blinn%E2%80%93Phong_reflection_model) model uses for light calculation:

<s>`const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffff00, side: THREE.DoubleSide } );`</s>

```js
const material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0xffff00, side: THREE.DoubleSide } );
```